# React Native encrypt data using OpenSSL

Tags: react-native, encryption

Here is my PHP code:

```php
$input_data = array("request_type" => "bill_status",
    "custno" => array(0 => "35677890GH"),
    "key" => "billstatusapiauth", "source" => "CustomerDashboard");
$create_json = json_encode($input_data, true);
$base_enc = base64_encode($create_json);
$create_encrypted = openssl_encrypt($base_enc, "aes-256-cbc", "billstatusapiauth", OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, "billrepository");
$create_encoded = base64_encode($create_encrypted);
$send_data = array("enc" => $create_encoded);
```

I want to achieve the encryption same like above in react native so I have used AES Crypto encryption.

Here is my React Native code

```js
var value = session?.businessInfo?.number;
dataArray.push(value);
const confidentialParams = {
    request_type: 'bill_status',
    custno: dataArray,
    key: 'billstatusapiauth',
    source: 'CustomerDashboard',
};

// To encode an object (This produces a string)
var encode = JSON.stringify(confidentialParams);
   
//convert encoded value into base64
const encodedbase64 = base64.encode(encode);
    
var ciphertext = CryptoES.AES.encrypt(
    JSON.stringify(encodedbase64),
    'billstatusapiauth',
).toString();

const newBase64 = base64.encode(ciphertext);
```

I have followed all the steps which has been written in PHP code but still I am not getting response from API. How can I achieve this in React Native?

Edit:
I am using import CryptoES from 'crypto-es'; to encrypt and decrypt the data.

Comment: `billstatusapiauth` is an *invalid* AES-256 key. A valid AES-256 key is 32 bytes in size. PHP *implicitly* pads this invalid key with 0x00 values to the required length. On the CryptoJS side, this must be done *explicitly*. The same applies to the IV, which must be 16 bytes long. Also, in the CryptoJS code, key and IV must be passed as `WordArray`. If there are further problems, specify the CryptoJS package used (there are several, especially in the context of react native).

Comment: @Topaco i am using import CryptoES from 'crypto-es'; to encrypt and decrypt the data

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comment, there are the following issues:

- For AES-256, a 32 bytes key must be used. The posted key `billstatusapiauth` is shorter and therefore invalid for AES-256. PHP *implicitly* pads the key with 0x00 values to 32 bytes. On the JavaScript side, the key must be *explicitly* expanded to 32 bytes with 0x00 values.
- For AES, a 16 bytes IV must be used. The posted IV `billrepository` is shorter and therefore invalid for AES. PHP implicitly pads the IV with 0x00 values to 16 bytes (also an appropriate warning is displayed). On the JavaScript side the IV must be explicitly extended to 16 bytes with 0x00 values.
- In the CryptoES code the key and IV must be passed as `WordArray` (if the key is passed as string CryptoES applies a key derivation function).

The code below shows a possible implementation with CryptoES. Since I didn't find a CDN that offers CryptoES, I'll use CryptoJS from *cdnjs.cloudflare.com* in the following ([CryptoES](https://github.com/entronad/crypto-es) is a [CryptoJS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) port compatible with ES6 and TypeScript). In my local environment CryptoES gives the same result:

```js
var CryptoES = CryptoJS; // for this test environment here

const confidentialParams = {
    request_type: 'bill_status',
    custno: ['35677890GH'],
    key: 'billstatusapiauth',
    source: 'CustomerDashboard',
};

var plaintext = JSON.stringify(confidentialParams);
var plaintextB64 = CryptoES.enc.Utf8.parse(plaintext).toString(CryptoES.enc.Base64);

var key = CryptoES.enc.Utf8.parse('billstatusapiauth'.padEnd(32, '\0'));
var iv = CryptoES.enc.Utf8.parse('billrepository'.padEnd(16, '\0'));

var ciphertext = CryptoES.AES.encrypt(plaintextB64, key, {iv: iv});

var ciphertextB64 = ciphertext.toString();
var ciphertextJson = {enc:ciphertextB64};
console.log(ciphertextJson); // {enc: "FRu6qofJyIn6zda1PzOTxXl7AQ65U+AKHIzaVAJ9mOFxNJBBmB/VaGGr4c3m2RiSkEGfgbl3HiVV6/H81UqH7ecnYC9ZqyQFKpTyyhxzkWUKYJ71eliicKh/Y1RCd2mT1wYgG1PCwtPp8opM8j7VMQOWSxJY5B42BHAmfRRd/GIWEdyXLyruAFapmZWLq47UKM8l4Z80cyrQ6oY1YEXU5Q=="}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

On the PHP side, `print_r($send_data)` returns for the data used:

```php
Array
(
    [enc] => FRu6qofJyIn6zda1PzOTxXl7AQ65U+AKHIzaVAJ9mOFxNJBBmB/VaGGr4c3m2RiSkEGfgbl3HiVV6/H81UqH7ecnYC9ZqyQFKpTyyhxzkWUKYJ71eliicKh/Y1RCd2mT1wYgG1PCwtPp8opM8j7VMQOWSxJY5B42BHAmfRRd/GIWEdyXLyruAFapmZWLq47UKM8l4Z80cyrQ6oY1YEXU5Q==
)
```

i.e. an identical ciphertext!

Security:
The key and IV used are vulnerabilities. Both are not only too short but also strings. Instead, both should be random byte sequences of the required length.
If really a string (instead of a random byte sequence) is to be used as key material, a key derivation function has to be applied (at least PBKDF2).
Furthermore, it is important that there must be no reuse of key/IV pairs. Therefore, with a fixed key, a random IV is commonly generated for *each* encryption (the IV is not secret and is usually concatenated with the ciphertext so that it is available during decryption).